# uWSGI routing rule is overriding static files

Tags: regex, configuration, routes, uwsgi, ini

I'd like the following route behavior:

- Any path that exists in `webapp/static/` should be routed to that file
- Any other path that doesn't start with `/auth` or `/api`should be routed to `webapp/static/pages/index.html`
- Route remaining requests to my uwsgi app.

I have the following uWSGI configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :$(PORT)
master = true
processes = 4
die-on-term = true
module = webapp:app
memory-report = true

;HSTS
route-host = ^localhost:(?:[0-9]+)$ goto:localhost
route-if-not = equal:${HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO};https redirect-permanent:https://${HTTP_HOST}${REQUEST_URI}
route-if = equal:${HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO};https addheader:Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; preload

route-label = localhost
check-static = %v/webapp/static/
route = ^(/?|/(?!(auth.*|api.*))(.*))$ static:%v/webapp/static/pages/index.html
```

The problem is that the final route rule is overriding the static files handler, even if I change their order..  Previously, I used the regex `^/?$` to only send requests to `/` to the index page, which worked perfectly, so it must have something to do with how the regex works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the static rule is evaluated after the regex one. The regex you have used matches also the `/webapp/static` path so we need to exclude that path too.

Try to modify the regex rule like this:

```
# I removed also unused matching groups and append '/' to the exclude path
route = ^(?:/?|/(?!(?:auth|api|webapp/static)/).*)$ static:%v/webapp/static/pages/index.html
```